# Can Malware infect a shared server?

Tags: malware

Hi there Ladies and Gents

I am asking this question because this weekend ahas seen me go from a fully haired man to a bold man in let them 24 hours.  Google found malware on three site we are running on a shared server.  All the files are HTML or Java.  I have done some research and this Malware software put a load of numbers and letters at the bottom of the HTML pages.  So, I have cleaned the files off the server, and replaced them with clean files from our own hard drives.  But within a few minutes the files are infected again.  Then looking at the file, there are no bits of code.  So when I go back to firefox and look again, after clearing the cache the same thing happens again, the red screen!  I am just wondering if, there could be a infection on the shared server and it could be infecting more than just our three website?

Sorry it's long winded - No sleep for 48 hours sorting this out and rebuilding the sites on another server we trust.

Kind regards to all who read this message.
John

Comment: what are you using to host the site?  apache?

Comment: Do not be so sure it is malware. I suggest you to do a complete virus and malware scan. Is it a Windows server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. it is possible for malware to infect a whole server.

Comment: Thank you for that Rowland, is there any way I could find out if this has happened before I go belletristic at the company?

Comment: If its not your server, there's little you can do (and it's possibly in their ToS to protect them from liability) - it may be another client of their that hasn't patched their Wordpress/Joomla/etc that allowed for the vector for attack - that's for them to determine from their logs